# How to check if value exist in two tables

Tags: ms-access, dcount

Hi I've searched the net and couldn't find the right answer to my question.

I have two tables `GCSALLDATA` and `GCS-RECONCILED`. They both have the same columns but I only need to focus on two `[Control Number]` (Short Text) and `[NotInDevTrack]` (yes/no)

I want to search `GCSALLDATA` for the Control Number found in `GS-RECONCILED`. If it's found Update the record.

From what I read using a `DCOUNT` should be able to do this, but wondered how would it cycle through all the records in the table?

Here is my attempt at using to use it

```
If DCount("[Control Number]", "GCSALLDATA", "Control Number=" & [GCS_Reconcile].[Control Number]) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Control number already in use")
Else
    MsgBox ("Control Number missing add it")
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've correctly understood what you mean when you state:

> I want to search `GCSALLDATA` for the Control Number found in `GS-RECONCILED`. If it's found Update the record.

You can use a simple `update` query to update records in `GCSALLDATA` for which there is a matching Control Number in `GS-RECONCILED`, for example:

```sql
update GCSALLDATA t1 inner join GS-RECONCILED t2 on t1.[Control Number] = t2.[Control Number]
set t1.NotInDevTrack = True
```

Assuming that you wish to set the `NotInDevTrack` field to `True` (`Yes`) for those numbers which match.

Comment: Wow that's beautiful. Thank you

Comment: is there a way to put a condition if t1 doesn't have t2.[Control Number] add t2.[ID], t2.[Current Status]?

Comment: @MaxineHammett That would require a separate `insert into` (append) query, but would be better placed as a separate question, since this question concerns updating records with matching values.